# Can we use ToString() or ternary operator with html helper in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

see the code

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
</div>
```

when i try to do it `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id.ToString())` then i was getting error. what was wrong to use `ToString()` in view ?

in view can we check null or `ternary operator` if null then return something else. show me few code sample. some one told me it is not possible rather all i need to do in model class. looking for guide line. thanks

Comment: The html helpers need a property accessor, but `.ToString()` is method, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to use a method here (`ToString()`) you should be receiving the following error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

As the error states, this helper can't be passed a method.

What exactly are you trying to do?  It seems as though you *might* be trying to handle a blank input into the text field.  The fix here would be to simply keep it as your original:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
```

And then if your `Id` property is type `int` you would have to test for 0.  This could give you a false "blank" condition.  Something you could do here is to set the `Id` property as type `int?` (nullable int):

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then on your post, check for `Id` to be null:

```
if (myModel.Id == null)
    // handle accordingly
```

Comment: in html helper can we ternary operator ?

Comment: @Mou What exactly are you trying to do?  What are you trying to accomplish with the helper?

Comment: see this code `@Html.EditorFor(model => (model.Name=="" ? "Empty" :model.Name ))`  can i write this kind of code in html helper ?

Comment: That is a check that should be done server side, before rendering the page.

Comment: @Mou just to note, no you can't do that as it doesn't make any sense. Html.EditorFor needs to reference a property; it's actually an expression that is being used in the parameter type which the rendering code will use to determine the name of the field for postback.